# SocketTimoutException in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm very new to Spring JDBC. I'm able to connect to my local MS SQL Server instance using manual code, but got the following exception using Spring JDBC:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host localhost, named instance \sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:470)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:511)
    at org.springdemo.demo1.CustomJDBCTemplate.getDBs(CustomJDBCTemplate.java:25)
    at org.springdemo.demo1.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:15)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host localhost, named instance \sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
```

SQL Browser Service is already running.

Following is the beans.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

<bean id="dataSource1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLExpress;integratedSecurity=true;" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLExpress;integratedSecurity=true;" />
</bean>

<bean id="customJDBCTemplate" class="org.springdemo.demo1.CustomJDBCTemplate">
    <property name="dataSources">
        <list>
            <ref bean="dataSource1" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As you can see, I've tried both spring JDBC and commons dbcp, but both failed.
Here's the main code:

```
package org.springdemo.demo1;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "beans.xml");
    CustomJDBCTemplate template = (CustomJDBCTemplate) context
            .getBean("customJDBCTemplate");

    SqlRowSet srs = template.getDBs();
    while (srs.next()) {
        System.out.println(srs.getString("name"));
    }
}
}
```

Here's the template class :

```
package org.springdemo.demo1;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;

public class CustomJDBCTemplate {
    private List<DataSource> dataSources;
    private List<JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateObjects = new ArrayList<JdbcTemplate>();

    public void setDataSources(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
        this.dataSources = dataSources;
        for(DataSource s : dataSources)
            this.jdbcTemplateObjects.add(new JdbcTemplate(s));
    }

    public SqlRowSet getDBs()
    {
        String query = "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');";
        return jdbcTemplateObjects.get(0).queryForRowSet(query);
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** @Shailendra - Here's the manual working code:

```
package jdbcexample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Class2 {

    final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLExpress;integratedSecurity=true;";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            // STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

            // STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql_getDBList = "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql_getDBList);

            // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                String dis = rs.getString("name");
                System.out.println(dis);
            }
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }// nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }// end finally try
        }// end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the "manual code" which successfully runs.

Comment: @Shailendra - added the working code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cost me a complete day to pull my hair out and reach to the conclusion that I'm really stupid :|
Turns out I was trying to put an escape sequence for '\' in the connection string for the Data Sources.
Removed and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing integratedSecurity=true; to integratedSecurity=SSPI

This might be the issue:
[JDBC: Simple MSSql connection example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523865/jdbc-simple-mssql-connection-example-not-working)

Similar
[Unable to establish database connection to SQL Server 2008 using java in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283034/unable-to-establish-database-connection-to-sql-server-2008-using-java-in-eclipse)

Comment: Did not work. Got the following exception:

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The property integratedSecurity does not contain a valid boolean value. Only true or false can be used.

Comment: Check links, might help

Comment: Tried changing Port Number according to the first link. Now even manual code stopped working.
Second link also did not help.

Comment: Edit: Restarted the services, manual code working now. But still Spring JDBC not working.